# Nginx: Proxy pass is adding port number when trying to open directory without trailing slash on end

Tags: nginx, centos, configuration, redirect

Everything works well except this part when a directory has no trailing slash in URL and it adds port and timeout page.

This is reverse proxy setup

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
    server_name example.org;
    port_in_redirect off;

    # SSL
    SSl setup here


# reverse proxy
location / {
proxy_pass https://ip:1981;
proxy_ssl_trusted_certificate ssl/example.pem;
proxy_ssl_protocols TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;
proxy_http_version  1.1;
proxy_cache_bypass  $http_upgrade;

proxy_set_header Upgrade            $http_upgrade;
proxy_set_header Connection         "upgrade";
proxy_set_header Host               $host;
proxy_set_header X-Real-IP          $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For    $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto  $scheme;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host   $host;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port   $server_port;
    }

}
```

Comment: Nginx is not adding the port number, the service at `ip:1981` is. You can either fix the service at `ip:1981` or if its a simple redirect, use `proxy_redirect`.

Comment: I tried with `proxy_redirect ip:1981 example.org/;` but it doesn't change anything.

Comment: Is that the correct string? Use `curl -I https://example.com/...` and see what value the `Location` response header contains.

Comment: I tried both `proxy_redirect ip:1981 /;` as it is for the whole domain. But nothing seems to fix when there's no trailing slash on end.